# Why marginal odds in frequency matched case-control?

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio, epidemiology, case-control-study

Let $D$ denote sampling with $D=1$ indicating subject being sampled and $D=0$ otherwise. $W$ denotes intrinsic variable of subjects, $X$ denotes exposure of interest and $Y$ denotes the binary outcome. The DAG is drawn below, where $D=1$ subjects were selected only.

[image]

I am following Cox's Case-Control Studies' Sec 1.3.2 statement in (2). Suppose I identified control s.t. control group $W$ distribution resemble to that of case group. In particular, this implies $W\perp Y$ only.

For binary $X$, we can estimate odds from 2 by 2 table formed by $X$ and $Y$ of the selected cases and controls.

$Q:$ Why does the book call the odds marginal odds here? Consider the marginal cell frequency of exposed and diseased cell. This would corresponds to $\sum_{W\in\{1,0\}}P(X=Exposured,Y=Diseased,W)=\sum_{W\in\{1,0\}}P(W|X=Exposured,Y=Diseased)P(X=Exposured,Y=Diseased)$.

We only know $W\perp Y$ not $W\perp X,Y$. It seems that this does not imply the calculated odds corresponds to marginal odds ratio. What is the use of the assumption on frequency matchiing?

$Q':$ If I am being naïve, table of $X$ and $Y$ marginalizes $W$, as you have collapsed $W$ in each cell. That should give marginal odds ratio regardless of matching frequency of $W$. Why does the book specifically call the odds ratio from the table of $X$ and $Y$ marginal odds ratio?